# Critical points of a function on a curve

Tags: calculus

Let $F(x,y) = xy$. Find the critical points of F on the curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$.

Thoughts:

I'm aware of critical points, however I'm not sure what the question is asking when it means find the critical points of F on the curve

solving: $\nabla F(x,y) = \lambda \nabla H(x,y)$ where $H(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 +x$ I get 3 crit points

Comment: I think critical point in this case means stationary point or extreme point. So you need to find extremes of the function $F(x,y)=xy$ on the curve $y^2=x^3-x$.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the points where the first partials are both equal to $0$ (i.e. the critical points) and also satisfy the curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$.

In other words, you are trying to solve the (overdetermined) system

$F_x = y = 0$

$F_y = x = 0$

$C = y^2 - x^3 + x = 0$.

Comment: But you already have the solution with $F_x = F_y = 0$ i.e. $x = y = 0$? How does the curve do anything? Using this I get solutions $(0,0)$,$(1,0)$,$(-1,0)$

Comment: @Warz, The curve restricts the solutions of $F_x$ and $F_y$ to being points on the curve.  You will notice that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ lie on the curve, but they do not satisfy $F_x = F_y = 0$.

Comment: Then the only solution is $(0,0)$ - I'm having troubles understand what's actually going on here. Is this tied into lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @Warz, Correct, the only solution is $(0,0)$.  We could potentially have a system where we have additional critical points that do not satisfy the curve.  The curve is just an additional constraint, and so we want to restrict our choice of critical points to ones that satifisfy it. In this case, however, the curve constraint does not change anything.

Comment: I think this is the incorrect method thinking about it. It is subject to the curve, solving your equations gives us only 1 solution. But, there are other solutions, if we solve $\nabla F(x,y) = \lambda \nabla H(x,y)$ where $H(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 +x$

Comment: OK.  Sure.  So then, you have following equations you want to solve:

Comment: $$y = \lambda(-3x^2 + 1)$$


$$x = \lambda(2y)$$


$$0 = y^2 - x^3 + x$$


Solving this system, you get 4 solutions, actually, but only $1$ of them is a critical point (by definition) of the original function.

Comment: @verictal.void How do you determine that only 1 of them is a critical point of the original function? The question is a critical point of F on the curve, not of F itself?

Comment: For instance, take a look at this: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_spring_09/PDF/11-08-Lagrange-Multipliers.pdf

Comment: The definition of a critical point of $F$ is a solution where all the partials are equal to $0$, no?  This is by definition of what it means to be a critical point

I used some software packages that solve nonlinear polynomials (Phcpack) and determined that there were 4 unique solutions (5 solutions if you included a solution that you found that had a different lagrange multiplier, but with the $(x,y)$ values the same).  Only 1 of those solutions (the origin, $(0,0)$) actually satisfied the definition of being a critical point since they did not satisfy each partial being $0$.

Comment: The question is to find a critical point on the curve, i.e. a point that is critical for $F$ and that also lies on the curve $C$.  The other solutions of the system with the lagrange multipliers are not critical points because they do not satisfy the definition.

Comment: But using the function $H(x,y)$ which searching online, gives us the minimum and maximum points of $F$ subject to the curve, then we gather $3$ min/max points, but all min/max points are also critical points, so there are 3 critical points of F subject to the curve.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm confused by what this question is actually asking.  You are right, and I am wrong.